# "Select folder for offline use" without storing attachments

Tags: email, thunderbird, cache, imap

Is it possible to tell Thunderbird to make a folder available for offline use, but to fetch attachments on demand? I'd like to be able to fulltext-search my archives when offline, yet I hardly ever need the attached files.

I know I can limit the size of messages downloaded, but this also seems to exclude the message's body.

This question addresses a similar issue, but for Outlook. [Strip attachments from emails to disk but leave a link in the email to the attachment](https://superuser.com/q/51133/99136)

Comment: Have you checked if there is a plug-in that does what you want?  If there isn't then a plug-in will be required since Thunderbird does have this feature by default.

Comment: @Ramhound: Just searched all add-ons for "Attachment", found nothing...